# Using arrays to record number of clicks on a button

Tags: javascript

last night I was coding a little piece of JS code that records the number of mouse clicks on a keypad (akin to a mobile phone) and with each successive press a new value would be entered into a textbox. This is how I've got so far.

The difficulty last night was that I set count as a global variable which was carried across meant if a user clicked on 1 and 2 they would get 1D in the text box when they should be getting 12:

http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/7/

In my most recent code I've tried to create an array so initially we have:

```
[0,0,0,0]
```

And each time the user clicks a button then e.g 1 and then 2 - the array updates to:

```
[1,1,0,0]
```

The values at 1 in array 1,2 are then added to the text box.

When the array element equals 4 then the array element resets to 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/9/

I've been having difficulty achieving this and feel that the logic behind my coding is awkward. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the id of element where you start counting index:

```
var count = 0
var elId;
function input(number) {
    if (elIf != number) {
        elId = number;
        count = 0;
     }

    number = number.split(".");
    document.getElementById('search').value += number[count];
    count++;
    if (count == 4) {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/15/

**update:** http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/19/

Comment: When the same button is pressed several times - what would be the best way of counting through the array then outputting the element. e.g. if I press 1 three times instead of getting 1ab I get b - but obviously switching to another button would offset that?

Comment: Here is example with timeouts. Probably you are looking for example like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/19/. If you clicking faster than 1 second letter will change.

Comment: Wow thanks! What does `window.clearTimeout(endTimeout);` do? Is it the same as the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: It's opposite to setTimeout. It clears the timeout before it's fired.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { isInTyping = false; }, 1000)` what is the purpose of this statement? I don't understand it either. Once I understand it however - the code will make sense to me.

Comment: after 1000 milliseconds it will set variable `isInTyping` to false and when you start clucking you bettons it will think that you just start typing and will put new letter, otherwise if this flag is true it will just change to the next letter.

Comment: So the `function()` bit means it will run within the current function of input?

Comment: nope, `function() {  }` - it's just declaration of the timeout handler. Because of `isInTyping` global variable this function can get access to it and change it.

Comment: This is my final solution what do you think: [http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/20/](http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/20/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more dynamic solution using an object map and a array.

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VMaSV/

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="text">
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="input(1, [1, 'a', 'b', 'c']);">1</td>
        <td onclick="input(2, [2, 'd', 'e', 'f']);">2</td>
        <td onclick="input(3, [3, 'g', 'h', 'i']);">3</td>
        <td onclick="input(4, [4, 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']);">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
var obj = {
    "id-1": 0,
    "id-2": 0,
    "id-3": 0,
    "id-4": 0
}
function input(id, a) {
    var chars = a[obj["id-"+id]];
    document.getElementById('search').value += chars;
    obj["id-"+id]++;
    if (obj["id-"+id] == a.length) {
        obj["id-"+id] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What are the advantages of this method over the one above?
2) Same question I asked @Samich - when the same button is pressed several times - what would be the best way of counting through the array then outputting the element. e.g. if I press 1 three times instead of getting 1ab I get b - but obviously switching to another button would offset that? Would it be easier to implement here?